# Use two loops inside a dictionnary

Tags: python

I have two lists:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [1, 2, 3]
```

I would like to have them like:

```
{1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3}
```

I tried:

```
print({k: v for k in a for v in b})
```

But I get:

```
{1: 3, 2: 3, 3: 3}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `zip()` inside `dict()`:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [1, 2, 3]

print (dict(zip(a,b)))
```

Output:

```
{1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3}
```